# SQL Case() casts results as integer

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

Working with a Pervasive SQL database, I have a complex SQL SELECT statement that contains the following:

```
    CASE l."Position"
        WHEN 3 THEN "PIC"
        WHEN 4 THEN "SIC"
        WHEN 22 THEN "FA"
        ELSE ''
    END AS "Position"
```

`l."Position"` is stored in the database as TINYINT.  Obviously I'm trying to return a string -- basically convert a numeric code to an understandable label.  But the result in that column is always `0` because (apparently) it's outputting an integer field and "PIC" (for example) is 0 when cast as a number.  If I change it to...

```
    CASE l."Position"
        WHEN 3 THEN 123
        WHEN 4 THEN 456
        WHEN 22 THEN 789
        ELSE ''
    END AS "Position"
```

...it returns the three digit numbers as expected, so I know the Case itself is working fine.

How do I tell Case() to return a string/varchar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this fixed if you use single quotes for the string constants throughout?

```
(CASE l."Position"
     WHEN 3 THEN 'PIC'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'SIC'
     WHEN 22 THEN 'FA'
     ELSE ''
 END) AS "Position"
```

Another possibility is that you should name the new column a different name, like `Position_Name`.  If you are selecting "Position" itself in the query, then the two might be getting confused.

Comment: Yes! It was the double quotes. I changed it to single quotes and it works great. This isn’t my usual flavor of database, so I am not used to using double quotes at all

Comment: Worth mentioning: assigning the calculated field name to the same as the origin name was not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Example [from the official documentation](http://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/sqlref%2Fsqlref.CASE_(expression).htm), It does not seem that this would cause problem

> ```
> SELECT last_name, first_name,
> CASE
> WHEN scholarship = 1 THEN 'Scholastic'
> WHEN citizenship <> 'United States' THEN 'Foreign Study'
> WHEN (date_of_birth >= '1960-01-01' AND date_of_birth <= '1970-01-01') THEN 'AJ-44 Funds'
> ELSE 'NONE'
> END
> AS 'Funding Program' FROM Person ORDER BY last_name
> ```

Which results as that the problem is not in CASE statement itself, but on the `As Position` part where the Position is your column name wıth TINYINT data type. You should consider to use alias which is different from your column names.